# How to compare/validate many multiple fields against each other without duplicating FormControls

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have these fields:

```
field1
field2
field3
field4

this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
  'field1' = ['', [<control-specific-validations>]],
  'field2' = ['', [<control-specific-validations>]]
 }, { validator: isField1GreaterThanField2Validator}
 });
```

More validations I need:

```
- field3.value must be greater than field4.value
- field3.value must be greater  than field2.value + 1
- field4.value must be less than field1.value
```

How do you integrate these new validation requirements into the constructed form?

What I do **NOT** want to do is to setup a

```
formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => { });
```

for each field and then have many if/else there.

Then I could remove the whole reactive forms module, use 2way-databinding and render a error string in the ui when the validation expression is true.

Comment: make a unique custom validator over all the form, give different response acording the conditions, show a error depending your response

Comment: so you say the isField1GreaterThanField2Validator should be my unique custom validator handling the conditional logic for all formcontrol`s ? Is that correct?

Answer (score 13):

You can use a custom validator to do this. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Here is a working example of what you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/isgreaterthanotherfield-custom-validator

The validator function itself looks like this:

```
greaterThan(field: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const group = control.parent;
    const fieldToCompare = group.get(field);
    const isLessThan = Number(fieldToCompare.value) > Number(control.value);
    return isLessThan ? {'lessThan': {value: control.value}} : null;
  }
}
```

I am using the `parent` property on the control to access the other field.

Note that you cannot set that validator in the form initialization, since the field you are basing it on is not yet defined.

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  field1: 0,
  field2: 0
});

this.myForm.get('field2').setValidators(this.greaterThan('field1'));
```

---

Update: I took it a step further and implemented a custom validator which accepts a predicate function so you can use the same validator for all your comparisons.

See it in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/comparison-custom-validator

It uses the same approach as above, but is a bit more flexible since you can pass in any comparison. There are some edge cases the example doesn't consider, like passing a form field name that doesn't exist, if the form field you pass does not actually use numbers / the types don't match up, etc, but I believe that is outside the scope of the question.

This was an interesting question and I enjoyed working on it.

For quick reference, here is what the entire component looks like with the flexible custom validator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  field2HasError: boolean;
  field3HasError: boolean;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      field1: 0,
      field2: 0,
      field3: 0,
      field4: 0
    });

    const field1MustBeGreaterThanField2 = 
      this.comparison('field1', (field2Val, field1Val) => {
        return Number(field2Val) < Number(field1Val);
      });

    const field3MustBeGreaterThanField2Plus1 =
      this.comparison('field2', (field3Val, field2Val) => {
        return Number(field3Val) > (Number(field2Val) + 1);
      });

    this.myForm.get('field2').setValidators(field1MustBeGreaterThanField2);
    this.myForm.get('field3').setValidators(field3MustBeGreaterThanField2Plus1);

    this.myForm.get('field2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.field2HasError = this.myForm.get('field2').hasError('comparison');
    });

    this.myForm.get('field3').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.field3HasError = this.myForm.get('field3').hasError('comparison');
    });
  }

  comparison(field: string, predicate: (fieldVal, fieldToCompareVal) => boolean): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      const group = control.parent;
      const fieldToCompare = group.get(field);
      console.log('fieldToCompare.value', fieldToCompare.value);
      console.log('field.value', control.value);
      const valid = predicate(control.value, fieldToCompare.value);
      return valid ? null : {'comparison': {value: control.value}};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: field1: has value 1 and field2: has value 0, but still the error is visible. Please repro that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your question is asking how to validate a form control based on a value in another form control without imperatively settings errors by subscribing to the value changes. I've demonstrated how to do that using custom validators. You can change the behavior to meet your needs by adjusting the logic / conditions, but the general approach is outlined there for you.

Comment: Have a look: https://ibb.co/e1tApG As long as the code is not correct how do I know what you propose will work in a more refined state?

Comment: Fixed it.  It was a typo (`>` rather than `<`). The other validator is working as desired already.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I was settings the error state of the DOM element incorrectly, even though the validators were working fine. I fixed the bug now so you can see it working in the sample app. Does this approach work for you?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that situation in my fork. Are you using this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/comparison-custom-validator?

Comment: yes your above link: https://imgur.com/a/GVVJc I just added the form.valid check...

Answer (score 2):

//your .ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      field1: 0,
      field2: 0,
      field3: 0,
    }, { validator: this.customValidator }); //a unique validator

  }
  customValidator(formGroup: FormGroup) {         
    let errors:any={};
    let i:number=0;
    let valueBefore:any=null;
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);           
      if (valueBefore)
      {
        if (parseInt(control.value)<valueBefore)
        {
          let newError:any={['errorLess'+i]:true}  //create an object like,e.g. {errorLess1:true}
          errors={...errors,...newError};  //Concat errors
        }

      }
      valueBefore=parseInt(control.value);
      i++;
    });
    if (errors)
      return errors;
  }
}
```

The .html like

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  field1:
  <input formControlName="field1">
  <br> field2:
  <input formControlName="field2">
  <div *ngIf="myForm.hasError('errorLess1')">Field 2 less that field 1</div>
  <br> field3:
  <input formControlName="field3">
  <div *ngIf="myForm.hasError('errorLess2')">Field 3 less that field 2</div>
</form>
```